# Настройки IDE под конкретный проект

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ide

Приветствую!

Существует ли в PhpStorm(Intellij), возможность указывать настройки для определенного проекта?
Например: включать нужный плагины, указывать codestyle, указывать нужный отладчик(у меня каждый проект работает в своем docker-контейнере).

Comment: Ну конечно. Есть default settings, а есть settings проекта. Кнопочка в тулбаре с гаечный ключом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В IDE от JetBrains существует [два типа настроек](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html):

1. Настройки проекта
2. Настройки IDE

Настройки проекта специфичны для каждого проекта и хранятся в директории .idea проекта.
Настройки IDE располагаются:

- В Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.PhpStormXX\config`
- В Linux: `~/.PhpStormXX/config`

В настройки можно попасть через `File | Settings` контекстного меню или нажатием `Ctrl+Alt+S`

[image: Settings]
Вам нужно исходить из того, какого типа настройки вы хотите менять. Например, code-style - действует на уровне IDE, т.е. иметь для каждого проекта собственный code-style без переключения его каждый раз вручную вряд ли возможно. В то же время опции Run/Debug - это операции уровня проекта, значит возможность иметь уникальные конфигурации отладки для каждого проекта есть.

[Подробнее о настройках](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/IDE+and+Project+Settings+in+PhpStorm)